# Probabilistic approach to simulation of answers to a multiple choice question knowing each answer's probability of choice.

Tags: probability

I'm afraid my title is not helpful, but I hope I can make it clearer here. I'm really not well versed in probability so apologies for any mistake.

Let's say I have asked a first sample a multiple choice question with $n$ possible answers. And let's say this sample answered $i$ with "probability" $p_i$.

I now want to simulate the second sample of $m$ answerers as follows:

for each person $j\in[1,\dots,m]$ I generate $n$ random (uniformly in $[0,1]$) "noises" $r_{j,i}$ and assign to each answer a score $s_{j,i}(k):=r_{j,i} p_i^k$, $k$ a real number. The answer with the largest score is the one $j$ will choose.

Doing it for all $m$ answerers I get some new, let me say, probabilities $q_i(k)$.

What is the $k$ that minimizes the norm $|q(k)-p|$?

I would guess $k=1$, but a quick python simulation seem to suggest that's not the case.